# How to fix endless axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm building a Spotify web app now using its API. I'm making a get request to get album data of a specific artist. When I try the code below, handleClick is called endlessly in Albums.js. Does it have to do with asynchronous?

Albums.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import AlbumCard from "./AlbumCard";

export class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { albums: [] };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  async handleClick() {
    const {
      match: { params },
    } = this.props;
    console.log(params.id);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4000/albums/${encodeURIComponent(params.id)}`,
        {
          params: {
            id: params.id,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(`Returned album data from the server: ${res}`);
      this.setState({ albums: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      //   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
          {/* {`${id}'s albums`} */}
          {console.log(this.handleClick())}
          {console.log(this.state.albums)}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Albums;
```

server.js

```
app.get("/albums/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums(req.params.id).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.body.items);
    res.json(data.body.items);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it has to do with you calling `handleClick` inside `render`.

Inside your `handleClick`, you call `setState` and when state is set `render` is called and then `handleClick` is called again, which sets the state again, which causes `render` to be called again etc.

You probably meant to set `handleClick` as an event handler on a button inside `render`

So, the following would NOT cause an endless loop and would probably be closer to what you actually wanted to do

```js
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
          {console.log(this.state.albums)}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `handleClick` inside render method (in console.log).

So here is the flow:

- component is rendered and handleClick is called and you set state
- component is re-rendered and handleClick is called again and you set state
- component is re-rendered .... and so on

So have a button and provide a reference of handleClick to `onClick` event

```js
<div className="container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
  {/* {`${id}'s albums`} */}
  {/* {console.log(this.handleClick())} //<---don't do this */}
  <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
  {console.log(this.state.albums)}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the API in the `render()`, that is why it is endless.

```
export class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { albums: [] };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.handleClick() // I don't know why its name is `handleClick`.
  }
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
          {/* {`${id}'s albums`} */}
          {/* console.log(this.handleClick()) */} /* should be removed */
          {console.log(this.state.albums)}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```